# css: issue with z-index

Tags: html, css

I have this nice [post-it](http://www.ballyhooblog.com/realistic-css3-box-shadows/) with pure CSS. I've implemented it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g29ns/2/). Looks all very nice!

However, in my situation I have also a div with css as follows:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

With that div in place, the css effect used on the post-it is messed up. It seems to be an issue with the `z-index`!
However, I've fiddled with the `z-index`es, but I cannot fix it. Checkout this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g29ns/1/) which shows the issue. Is there anyway the postit can be fixed ?

Comment: Could you please define your 'issue'

Comment: why here two jsfiddle.?

Comment: I've added an explanation. One jsfiddle is without the 'div', in which case the post-it looks just fine. The second one has this div, which has an effect on the post-it styling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset the z-index on your box div. So the z-index statements on the pseudo selectors apply correctly. Add the following line:

```
#box {
    [...]
    z-index: auto;
}
```

As the others anwers mention this. Your general div style conflicts with the z-index statements at :before and :after.
But I guess you have a reason for this.

Answer (score 4):

According to your html structure

```
<div></div>
<div id="box">
       Text Here
</div>
```

You have applied CSS to div

```
div {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: blue;
   z-index: -3;
}
```

And you are applying seperate CSS to "#box" div along with pseudo properties.

**But as you define z-index for div, it gets applied to all div elements.**

Hence, the z-index property for :before and :after alos get applied along with same property as mentioned for all div elements.

**So to overcome this you need to apply some class or id to parent div**

Please refer to [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/q43wq/1/) for the same.

**Or apply `z-index: auto` in #box div**

Please refer to [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/q43wq/2/) for the same.

Comment: @Jeanluca Scaljeri, are you fine with explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Your style for 'div' is getting applied to both the Divs'
Use something like this:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<div id="box">
   Text Here
</div>

#myDiv {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: blue;
 z-index: -3;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give you div a classname so all your div's will get that css.
This will work

http://jsfiddle.net/g29ns/4/

```
    <div class="givethisdivaclass"></div>
<div id="box">
       Text Here
</div>


div.givethisdivaclass {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: blue;
   z-index: -3;
}

#box{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    margin:50px auto;
    position:relative;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fefbb0), to(#fff955));
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#box:after{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 8px 12px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    background:transparent;
    bottom:10px;
    right:9px;
    width:70%;
    height:70%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg) skew(10deg);
    z-index: -2;
}

#box:before{
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 11px 11px 32px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    background:transparent;
    bottom:46px;
    right:41px;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg) skew(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <!-- gave a unique id to the div to avoid the issue -->
<div id="boxNew"> </div>
```

Like this,

```
#boxNew {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: blue;
   z-index: -3;
}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W2Md9/)